# How to take user input and display in italics in rich text box

Tags: c#

```
private void showItalizedButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   titleTextBox.Text = "";
   italicsRichTextBox.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi Title \i italics \i0  end}";
}
```

This is what i have to far and where i have typed italics in between the escape sequence i need whatever the user types in a textbox to display in italics and the Title and end be before and after..
So it would look like this when the button is clicked   Title *Dummy Title* end.. if anyone has any suggestions i would appreciate it..

Comment: Something like `italicsRichTextBox.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi Title \i" + titleTextBox.Text +  "\i0  end}";`?

Comment: i tried that and it says Error Unrecognized escape sequence at \i0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not an expert in RTF, but I belive the right syntax is:

```
italicsRichTextBox.Rtf = @"{\rtf1\ansi Title {\i " + titleTextBox.Text + "} end}";
```

Also make sure you capture `titleTextBox.Text` *before* clearing it.

Comment: yes that is what i needed to do and i need to add                                     title myTitle = new title(titleTextBox.Text);